# Problem with Booting

Tags: boot

So im having problems with my Dell Inspiron 3553. I just installed Ubuntu Desktop, and every time I boot, It goes into Diagnostics. Ive tried to reinstall it, and it does the same thing. when the stick is in it just goes to that. The reason I know it works is... well... it comes like the factory! :/ But it ran Windows 10 out of the factory.

Help?
thanks! -Ryan

Comment: Can you please clarify your question with more information, and perhaps photographs of what you see, or pasting any errors.  As it is, your question doesn't make much sense, and I am having difficulty following.  For example, what 'stick' are you talking about?  When you say diagnostics, which diagnostics? Is it Linux diag, or Windows diag? Did you disable safeboot/UEFI in the bios?  Did you setup multiple paritions? did you wipe windows completely? We need more informaton to help.

Comment: im using a 32 GB SD card now as Inspirons can boot from them. Diagnostics meaning the one that comes with the PC. In my case, Dell SmartDiagnostics, witch comes with the bios.My boot settings are Legacy boot, Safebooter off, with advanced legacy enabled. the partitons were what they do default. I think the Diag is basted on the NT kernel or something. I wiped the drive witch had Windows 10 Home on it. whenever i boot, it goes straight to the SD card and misses the hard drive. when i boot from the HD, it just goes straight to diagnostics and says theres no OS on it.

Comment: UPDATE: found out how to get into Grub, I got this: 
(hd0): Error: fine '/boot/grub/x86-64-efi/xxxx.mod'(x6) Not found.
Device (hd0): No known file system Detected. (This is the SD Card i used)
(hd0,msdos1): SD card again.
(hd1): The main drive. says there isint a file system to it.
(hd1,gpt3): none detected file system, sector 3 of the main drive
(hd1,gp2): Identified as ext* file system, also main drive
(hd1,gp1): Identified as fat (fat32, i presume?), main drive again
(proc): Identified as procfs, Probally the huge file when installing?
(memdisc): i dont know.

Comment: Please edit and improve the question with your new information instead of dribbling updates into the comments.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you wiped out the uefi boot partition on the hard drive, you still need this partion eventhough you went to Legacy Boot ... the system BIOS is still looking for this, you need to recreate the partition table to include that first partition ... then you can go from there ...

That error message from GRUB tells the story its missing the /boot/ partition ...

I'm really new at this but I did the same thing ... so I took my backup copies of the windows restore that I made when I got the computer put it all back then when I restarted it I booted the Linux install and blew it all away and installed Linux ... Linux re-formatted ever thing again, and I got it working ... I originally thought I had bad HHD .... good luck - fixitmr-

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54658/discussion-on-answer-by-angelo-g-massolin-problem-with-booting).